# Opamp confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, nodal-analysis

[image: Coursera DC Opamp Circuit]

I would really appreciate a little help here if someone explain me why his Voltage is 4v while mine is 10/3

and one more thing: whats the point of Applying KCL at node 1 when 5v is already known at Non-inverting terminal.

My Approach:

$$\frac{5-V_o}{10k}-\frac{V_o}{20k}=0$$

$$V_o=\frac{10}{3}$$

Comment: You did not include the 0.1mA current source in your equation.

Comment: @G36 why would i do that ? i am writing equation for node $$V_o$$

Comment: But the current source current must flow into the 10k resistors (op-amp input does not consume any current). And this current will produce a voltage drop equal to 1V. And this is why Vo is 5V - 1V = 4V

Comment: Please, post a nicely cropped image. Most of the image area is irrelevant (is either blank or just UI space). Show some effort. Clicking on such an image to clearly see important details when it could have been zoomed/cropped in advance is *very* annoying.

Comment: Vo/20K does not contribute to the current at your node 1, and you *must* take into account the 0.1mA current.

Comment: @G36 Thank you i understand what was i am doing wrong

Comment: There are three wires connected to the Vo node, and you've only accounted for the current in two of them in your node equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing the KCL equation for the node you marked as \$V_o\$, you need to also include the current provided by the op-amp's output pin.

But there's no way to know what that current is (right away), so we don't use KCL at that node to solve this kind of problem.

Instead, we use the assumption that there is no current in to the op-amp's input pins, and that because of negative feedback the inverting input pin will be driven to the same potential as the non-inverting input pin.

Then we know that the potential at node "1" is 5 V. And the current through the 10 kohm resistor is 0.1 mA.

From those conditions, we can find the potential at \$V_o\$.